# @Transactional doesnt work whereas DefaultTransactionDefinition works

Tags: spring, jpa

I am upgrading my application from Spring3 to Spring 4. In my existing application we were using `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` which creates the transaction along with new request. 
Now I am using JPA also so even if I use `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` it doesn't associate transactions with it. So I had to put transaction manually in all my controller methods.

Due to legacy code, the controller classes have lots of business logic instead of distributing it properly to service layer. 
Now if I put `@Transctional` annotation on controller method, then it doesn't work whereas if I use manual transaction through `DefaultTransactionDefinition` then it works properly.
Also, if I remove the business logic of controller methods to service layer, and put `@Transactional` annotation to service layer, then it also work fine. But these changes are tedious and my application is very big, so cant do it.
Please let me know why `@Transactional` doesn't work in my case if I put it in controller, how should I get it working.
I am not using AspectJ for transaction management.

**Tried approaches:**

1. Code at both places :   code in dispatcher-servlet.xml along with appliacationContext.xml but still the controller transactions are failing.
2. Moved bean for urlMapping into applicationContext.xml but still it fails.

Comment: First of all annotating your controllers with `@Transactional` is not a very smart thing to do. Your transactional boundary is the service layer not the incoming web request!. Also the `Open*InViewInterceptor` doesn't open a transaction it opens a `Session` or `EntityManager` that is something else then a transaction!. That being said. You probably have the enablement of transactions in the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` whereas your controllers are loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` enable transactions in that as well

Comment: show us your transaction configuration. aspectJ? Maybe controller classes are excluded for auto-proxying, or live in another context, or arent Spring managed at all

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for your input. I do have <context:annotation-config /> <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>  code in my dispatcher-servlet.xml but still the controller transactions are failing. Please let me know if I am missing some otherthing

Comment: @AlexSalauyou - I am not using aspectJ. Please elaborate more on controller classes excluded for auto-proxying.

Comment: Please let me know what am i missing